# A way to merge td's in a table

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

So I'm trying to create a weekly calendar.
I coded a loop in javascript creating the empty table and then afterwards modified the innerHTML of the appropriate td's from values taken from an SQL table using php and javascript.
My problem is that when I set the rowspan of the specific td instead of merging with the next td's it is moving them to the end of my table. If I have 2 more reputation points i will post pictures to show my problem.

[image: Without any rowspans]
[image: With rowspans]

Here is my code if you want to take a look at it

```
                // Declare usefull information about the database and host
            $mysql_host = "-host info-";
            $mysql_database = "-database info-";
            $mysql_user = "user";
            $mysql_password = "pass";

            // open the connection
            $link = mysql_connect($mysql_host,$mysql_user,  $mysql_password, $mysql_database);

            // connect to the database
            mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $link) or die('database not selected'. mysql_error());


            // Select * from the table created in the database
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Appointment;")
            or die("Could not query:" . mysql_error());

            echo "<script type='text/javascript' > "
                . "var hours = new Array('9:00','9:30','10:00','10:30','11:00','11:30', "
                . "'12:00','12:30','13:00','13:30','14:00','14:30','15:00','15:30');"
                . ""
                . "var days = new Array('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat');"
                . ""
                . "for (  i = 0; i < 14 ; i++ ) "
                . "{"
                . "document.write('<tr id='+hours[i]+':00'+'>');"
                . "document.write('<th>'+ hours[i]+'</th> '); "
                ." for ( k = 0 ; k < 6; k++)"
                ."{"
                . "document.write('<td id='+days[k] +'> </td>'); "
                . "}"
                . "document.write('</tr>');"
                ."}"
                . " </script> ";

                while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
                {
                    $timestamp = strtotime($row['Date']);
                    $day = date('D', $timestamp);
                    $from = $row['StartTime'];
                    $to = $row['EndTime'];
                    $rowspan = determinRowSpanBetween($from,$to);

                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> "
                    . " var divToAddTo = GetElementInsideContainer('".$from."','".$day."');"
                    . "divToAddTo.className = 'busy';"
                    . "divToAddTo.rowspan='".$rowspan."';"
                    . "divToAddTo.innerHTML='Something to do';"


                    . "function GetElementInsideContainer(containerID, childID) {"
                    . " var elm = {};"
                    . "  var elms = document.getElementById(containerID).getElementsByTagName('*');"
                    . "  for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {"
                    . "   if (elms[i].id === childID) {"
                    . " elm = elms[i];"
                    . " break;"
                    . " }"
                    . "}"
                    . "return elm;"
                    . "}"

                    . " </script>" ;


                }
```

the function determinRowSpanBetween is created later on in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a rowspan > 1 in a td that is only supposed to take up one space (i.e. one that is not merged with other td's) will cause a whole bunch of errors. Make sure you account for every row you add to rowspan.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to do so ?

Comment: Try having a counter in your while loop that will count the number of rows added in rowspan, then subtracting that value from the 14 in your for loop. That way, it will show the correct number of rows (I don't know if this will lead to problems regarding the actual content you are trying to display. You would need to upload pictures for me to identify that...).

Comment: I'll upload the pictures right now! I have enough reputation points thank you

Comment: Okay, I see what you're trying to do. Firstly, will the start/end times always be within the range of times shown on the table?

Comment: Yes they will be within the range of times shown , also I'm not sure how to do so since my while loop starts executing after my for loop is already done

Comment: Also, will you ever be using colspan here?

Comment: No, I don't need to use colspan

Comment: Yeah so you are going to have to create function that given a start/end time, will return the number of rows that are to be filled. You have to call this function within the for loop while the table is being created. Also, you will have to have a counter that will skip all td's in that column which extends over multiple rows.

Comment: Okay! So my determinRowSpanBetween  already determins the number of rows used I will try that and get back to you thank you

Comment: FINALLY 
I fixed it thank you for your help 
I did what you said but it took me forever 
I'm still learning :)